# Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS: Internet connection not working, have tried forum fixes

Tags: server, internet, ethernet

So, I've installed Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS because of it's minimal processor/memory usage on a former compute node that I've repaired. My goal is to get it connected to my home internet through my cable modem/ethernet so that I can install the various packages I need to compile and run my particle simulation packages. Unfortunately, I have tried the standard approaches given on several forums including this one, and I have not been successful.

I am very much a novice/absolute beginner at all of this, so I appreciate all of the time and help!

Here is what I have tried thus far:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Then I edited the network interface file so it looks like this:

```
#The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#The primary network interface -- use DHCP to find our address
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Now I execute this:

```
dhclient -r

sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

For which I get this:

```
*Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces
*Reconfiguring network interfaces...
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 1355
```

Then when I try to ping google:

```
ping 64.233.169.104
```

I get nothing displayed....

Now, when I run:

```
route -n
```

I get...

```
Kernal IP routing table 
Destination    Gateway       Genmask        Flags  Metric  Ref    Use   Iface
0.0.0.0        98.180.56.1   0.0.0.0         UG     100    0      0     eth0
98.180.56.0    0.0.0.0       255.255.252.0   U      0      0      0     eth0
```

I very much appreciate any help that you can give me!

Thank you,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

To me sounds like cable problem.  Other problems could be port plugged into on  either the switch or the computer has a problem.  Final cause might be the ethernet card.

Is your ethernet card support by the version of 12.04 LTS?  Be sure to try the latest revision 12.04.2 LTS to be sure.